# Calling module class methods without module name in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to substitute

```
@m1 = MyModule.method1
@m2 = MyModule.method2
@m3 = MyModule.method3
@m4 = MyModule.method4
```

with something like this

```
with MyModule do

  @m1 = method1
  @m2 = method2
  @m3 = method3
  @m4 = method4

end
```

in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Method calls without an explicit receiver have an implicit receiver of `self`, so in order to make `method1` a call to `MyModule.method1`, `self` needs to be changed to `MyModule`. That's easy enough, after all, that's what `instance_eval` and `instance_exec` are for.

However, instance variables also belong to `self`, that's why they are called *instance* variables, after all. So, if you change `self` to `MyModule`, then `@m1`, `@m2` etc. will also belong to `MyModule` and no longer to whatever object they belong to in your code example.

In other words, you need `self` to change but you also need `self` not to change. That's a contradiction, ergo, what you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
def with(context, &block)
  yield context
end

with MyModule do |m|
  @m1 = m.method1
  @m2 = m.method2
  ...
end
```

I'm not totally sure what benefit this gives you - could you be more specific about how you plan to use this?